# Controlling the size of a spinning loading icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks again for anyone who can help me with what should be a seemingly easy problem! I just can't figure it out for the life of me. I am creating a sign up page that includes two  areas. I want these input areas to be inline with an icon that comes up while it is checking the database.

I have everything setup and I think my html is proper. I have created a row that contains both the input box and the whirly loader I got from the internet. The only problem is when I run it the whirly loader is way too big and is not totally in line with the input box.

here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="Shattr Username or Email">
        <label id = "usernameLabel"></label>
    </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">  


            <div class="whirly-loader" id="usernameSpinner" style="display: none;">Loading...</div> 

    </div>
</div>
```

I then go in and point to the "whirly-loader" class, but nothing changes no matter what I set my width and height to. This may be too weird a question but if anyone has any suggestions that would be awesome. Here is my css:

```
 .whirly-loader{

 height:10%;
 width:10%;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your animation icon is set as a background to the `whirly-loader` selector? If yes, then just add `background-size: cover` and it should fit defined height and width.

BTW. Always paste your fiddle. It's easier to help.